# Connecting AirPort Express Base Station to Time Capsule

Tags: network, time-capsule

I have a Time Capsule that I am using to broadcast WiFi throughout my house.  This is working just fine.  The Time Capsule is upstairs and needs to remain there.  I recently bought a TV that has Internet capabilities if connected by a LAN cable to the Internet.  I do not want to run a LAN cable from the basement to the upstairs.

I also happen to have an unused AirPort Express Base Station lying around unused.  What I would like to do is plug in this Base Station next to the TV in the basement and run a LAN cable to this Base Station to the TV.

My question: Can I set things up so that the Base Station receives WiFi signals from the Time Capsule?

I've found hints on how to do this on the Internet.  What I really need are *detailed* steps on how to do it.  I don't want a bunch of options in setting this up, I just want one straightforward path on how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have an Airport express (or Time Capsule...), but the method is not as scary as you might be worried about.  First, setup your wireless network on the Time Capsule, make sure the settings with regards to B/G/N etc are ones that your Airport Express can read (you don't mention model numbers), so ensure you are not using N only if your Express cannot do N also.  Network mode should be "Create a Wireless Network".  Then, on your Express, set the mode to be "Extend a Wireless Network" - it will list the networks it can see (that it is capable of extending, hopefully), and with luck you will find that they are within range of each other.  You just need to apply the same settings re passwords and security etc here, and hey presto it should repeat the same wireless network, thus extending it's range.  The network settings tab within Airport Utility should be greyed out, as the device should just be passing on what the Time Capsule presents, and it's not capable of overriding them.  Anything you subsequently plus into the ethernet port should effectively drop you into the same LAN, using Wireless connection between the TC and AE to allow communication from your telly to the internet.

Comment: beat me to it (as I was typing away) so I won't repeat what he's said, only add a link to [Extending the range of an 802.11n network](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AirPortUtility/5.1/en/ap2124.html) that covers the basics in a step-by step.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind, as we don;t know the age of your Airport Express, there was a new version of Airport Utility that was released yesterday (I think), that is not compatible with some older AE routers.  When you start Airport Utility, it may ask to upgrade either itself, or your routers firmware etc.  I wouldn't touch anything just yet, and see how you get on with the existing software setup, as you won't want to get into the realm of reinstalling back-level apps just to get back to the starting point...

Comment: Excellent point. (It was in fact the lede to my own answer).

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing.  Can the LAN port (if "port" is the right word) on the AirPort Express Base Station act as an out to the TV?  Or can that LAN port only act as an input port?

Comment: The Ethernet Port on the bottom of an Airport Express will function as both an input and an output.  i.e. You can plug it into your broadband modem to broadcast that signal via wifi or you can wirelessly join an existing wifi network (as in the example above) and use that port to send a wired signal to another device, in this cases your television.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly that at home.

I setup the TimeCapsule:
Wireless ->

- **Network Mode**: Create a wireless network
- **Wireless Network Name**: *SomeName* You create yours.
- **Wireless Security**: I would recommend WPA2

And the Airport Express:
 - **Network Mode**: Extend a wireless network
 - **Wireless Network Name**: *SomeName* You use yours.
 - **Wireless Security**: Use the same parameters

After this it should work... You might have to adjust your internet settings though.

Answer (score 0):

When using any wireless router/device to extend a network you must use EXACTLY the same security method AND password on the remote device as is set on the main router. You must also ensure that the remote device is set to bridge mode ie. that it is not handling the distribution of addresses by DHCP for example.